# Using ifelse function to fill in column in list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataset where I added my pilot participant output as data frames to a list, sort of like this (example taken from another stackoverflow question):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- lapply(1:5, function(x){
  data.frame(a = sample(1:5,5), b = sample(1:5,5))
})
```

I then created a new variable group, that starts off empty.

```
  for (i in df){
    df <- lapply(df, transform, group = NA)
  }
```

I want to fill in this group based on a surprise measure between 1 and 5, which is a variable (column) in my dataframe. However, I am unsure how to call up this column. The following code gives me the error *invalid subscript type 'list'*.

```
  for (i in df){
    df[[i]]$group <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(df[[x]]['surprise'] <= 3, 1,
                                              ifelse(df[[x]]['surprise'] > 3, 2, NA)))
  }
```

Since it is a list of multiple data.frames, how would I go about avoiding that error?

Comment: What is `'surprise'` here ? There is no such column in the data.

Comment: `surprise` would be a second variable added to both dataframes in the list, ranging from 1 to 5.

Comment: So you already have that `surprise` variable in `df` list ?

Comment: yes exactly! @RonakShah

Answer (score 0):

You may try -

```
df <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  transform(x, group = ifelse(surprise <= 3, 1,ifelse(x > 3, 2, NA)))
})
```

Or using `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(df, ~.x %>%
     mutate(group = case_when(surprise <= 3 ~ 1, 
                              surprise > 3 ~ 2)))
```

Comment: Thank you! That does give me the error <i>object 'surprise' not found</i>. To maybe make it more clear: my df has a few columns, including trial, answer, and surprise. I thus need to call on the surprise column from my df and then use that to compute the groups

Comment: First `df` is a list. Is that right ? Second, you mentioned that `surprise` variable is already present in `df` so I am confused why do you get error as `object 'surprise' not found`. Can you provide a complete example (that includes `surprise` variable) with expected output so that it is easier to debug the issue ?